# При определенном разрашении экрана сворачивает каталог и по клику можно свернуть и развернуть, подскажите как доработать?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Всем привет.**

При разрешении width 700, сделал через медиа стили, чтобы срабатывал hover, что можно кликать на каталог, вообщем сделал подсветку при наведении, ну и курсор. Для того чтобы лишний раз кнопка не отсвечивала, а то будут кликать, я ведь хочу сделать чтобы сворачивание срабатывало когда разрешение width 700.

Как сделать по клику сворачивание и разворачивания каталога при разрешении width 700, я там резайс добавил, при достижении width 700, каталог сворачивается, но если назад растягиваю окно браузера, чтоб было выше чем width 700, не разворачивает каталог.

Добавил по клику свернуть или развернуть, свернуть срабатывает, а вот развернуть нет, видимо что-то не так сделал, и как мне сделать чтобы свернуть и развернуть когда кликаешь срабатывало только тогда когда разрешение экрана ниже чем width 700.

**Рабочий пример**

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/r4qkebsh/8/>
```

**Добавлено:**
Нашел ресайз который отрабатывает хорошо, при разрешении 700, сворачивает и разворачивает.

```
   $(window).on('resize', function() {
 var win = $(this);
 if (win.width() < 700) {
   $('.smgm').slideUp('slow');
 } else {
   $('.smgm').slideDown('slow');
 }
```

});

---

*Не по теме, это для тех кто говорит, что мол код не вставляешь прямо.
Пытался вставить фрагменты кода, открылось окно но чет не сразу, вставил туда код весь, и потом пытался добавить, не добавилось, окон не свернуть и т.д, пришлось f5 нажимать )*

Answer (score 0):

Удалось реализовать вот такой вариант.

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/316swLdq/1/>
```

Но вариант не полноценный, ресайз и клик работают хорошо, но определение экрана как-то не срабатывает, допустим если поставить разрешение браузера 600, потом обновить страницу, то по идеи должно свернуть, но не сворачивает каталог. Но если стоит чуть уменьшить или увеличить браузер, то есть растянуть туда сюда, то сразу срабатывает.

```js
   //ресайз
 $(window).on('resize', function() {
 var win = $(this);
 if (win.width() < 700) {
   $('.smgm').slideUp('slow');
 } else {
   $('.smgm').slideDown('slow');
 }
});

   //при клике скрывает или показывает подменю
   $(document).on('click', '#main_cat', function() {
    if (document.body.clientWidth < 700) {
        if ($('.smgm').css('display') == 'none' || $('.smgm').css("visibility") == "hidden") {
       $('.smgm').show('slow');
        } else {
       $('.smgm').hide('slow');
        }
    }
   });
```

```css
.catm{
  width: 23%;
  min-width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #2B9A48;
  padding: 0 13px 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
  position:relative;
  z-index:9999;
}
.catm b{
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.catm{
    display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:700px) {
.catm {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.catm:hover {
  background: #003511;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main_cat" class="catm sb">
<div><i class="icon-cat"></i><b>Каталог товаров</b></div>
<i class="icon-arbm"></i>
</div>

<ul class="smgm">
<li><a href="" title="">Раздел</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="">Раздел</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="">Раздел</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="">Раздел</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="">Раздел</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="">Раздел</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="">Раздел</a></li>
<li><a href="" title="">Раздел</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Нашел решение**
Теперь определение экрана срабатывает.

```js
if (document.body.clientWidth < 700) {
   $('.smgm').hide();
 }
```

Но есть маленький косяк, с мобилы, если развернуть  и спуститься вниз чуть, то он автоматом сворачивает, вот это я пока не решил еще.